# Spring boot insert json foreign key

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables called Country and State:

Country:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7254786319390105939L;

@Id
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "country_id", targetEntity=State.class)
@JsonBackReference
private Set<State> states;
}
```

State:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "state")
public class State implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3569874119390105939L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Country.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id",  referencedColumnName="id")
@JsonManagedReference
private Country country_id;
}
```

The repositories and the controllers work correctly and with Postman i can get and post fine in the table Country, but went i try to Post in State an error appears:

```
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
```

I'm using the necessary headers (Accept and Content-Type), so the problem must be the json i'm trying to post

This is the json i get in Postman using GET http://localhost:8080/state:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "California",
"country_id": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "US",
 }
}
```

This is the json i want to post http://localhost:8080/add_state

```
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Texas",
"country_id": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "US",
 }
}
```

Also is there a way to use only the id of the country instead of all the object in the Post json?

**UPDATE**

This didnt work:

```
produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Here is the code of the repository and controller:

Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class StateRepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager entityManager;

  public StateDTO insert(StateDTO state) {
      return entityManager.merge(state);
  }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class StateController {

    @Autowired
    StateRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add_state" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addState(@RequestBody StateDTO state){
        repository.insert(state);
    }

}
```

Comment: It might be relevant to show the code of the controllers that aren't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller does not support `application/json;charset=UTF-8` content type. You should add `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` to the controller definition, as shown below -

`@PostMapping(path = "/path", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })`